# Merge tags [botframework] and [ms-botframework]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are two tags about ms bot framework (dev.botframework.com):

[botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/botframework/info)

- 352 questions tagged
- created: 4 months ago by digitalbath
- viewed: 72 times
- active: 3 months ago
- editors: 2

> Questions about The Microsoft Bot Framework - framework for building intelligent chat services bots.

and [ms-botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-botframework) (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-botframework/info)

- 102 questions tagged
- created: 3 months ago by CodeNotFound
- viewed: 1 time
- editors: 0

> Microsoft Bot Framework is an SDK for Node.js and .NET for building rich text chat bots, and a platform for hosting those bots

I think both tags are about the same thing and may be merged.

(Is there a flag button to propose merge or deletion of tag? There is just created "extended-choice-parameter" which is used only once to be deleted)