# Please make [botframework] a synonym of [microsoft-bot-framework]

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

[botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) is an official Microsoft tag monitored by the Bot Framework support team, and it has 7763 questions. Despite the generic-sounding name, it refers to one specific Microsoft framework and not to bots in general.

[microsoft-bot-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-bot-framework) only has 29 questions.

That being said, I think [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) should be a synonym [microsoft-bot-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-bot-framework) and not the other way around. My reason is that [microsoft-bot-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-bot-framework) makes it more clear that this tag is specifically referring to the Microsoft Bot Framework and not to bots in general. There have been instances of users using the [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) tag for questions that aren't related to the Microsoft Bot Framework, so this change would help alleviate that problem.

Examples:

- [trying to hide some info logs on heroku, running a telegram bot (logs appear only when using python, not with nodejs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745927/trying-to-hide-some-info-logs-on-heroku-running-a-telegram-bot-logs-appear-onl)
- [Discord bot to mute everybody in voice channel not working (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146442/discord-bot-to-mute-everybody-in-voice-channel-not-working-python)
- [How are code injection game bot APIs made?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408951/how-are-code-injection-game-bot-apis-made)
- [Node.js Telegram Bot - Asking questions and collecting answers to build the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849503/node-js-telegram-bot-asking-questions-and-collecting-answers-to-build-the-resu)

Until recently, the [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) tag and a few other tags had a special Bot Framework icon to indicate that they are company-specific. Apparently a subscription expired and must be renewed, and until that happens the [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) tag will likely be misinterpreted more often.

(Apparently there used to be an [ms-botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-botframework) tag. It's sort of irrelevant now, but I wonder if it would have been better to keep that name instead of [botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework) when the two were merged: [Merge tags [botframework] and [ms-botframework]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330368/merge-tags-botframework-and-ms-botframework))

Comment: I find your argument compelling. However, since Microsoft employees are active in monitoring this tag (bless them!), it would be nice to get some of them to weigh in on this before a moderator pulls the trigger. Actually, it seems from your profile that you are one such Microsoft employee. Are you speaking for the team, and/or can you please confer with your team and ensure that this rename is something y'all can get behind? We mods aren't generally supposed to mess with tags that are sponsored, and even though the sponsorship has officially lapsed, I don't want to step on any toes here.

Comment: @CodyGray - Thank you for the feedback. That's a good idea, so I've just asked my team to weigh in.

Comment: I manage the Stack Overflow tag sponsorship for the Microsoft Bot Framework Group. 

From a practical perspective, does this make any difference to our customers? Is there any impact on SEO, or the ability to tag things?

Comment: @ChrisM. - Yes it does. We just got another question wrongly tagged with botframework today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146442/discord-bot-to-mute-everybody-in-voice-channel-not-working-python

Comment: Here's an interesting one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408951/how-are-code-injection-game-bot-apis-made

Comment: @CodyGray - Thanks again for looking at this, and sorry for taking so long, but I think we've reached an understanding. Our concern is that if [tag:botframework] isn't the "main" tag then we'll lose ownership of it, and then it would be possible for another company to sponsor it instead, effectively taking the name. Can you address this concern by letting us know how tag sponsorship works with synonyms? If we were to sponsor, say, [tag:microsoft-bot-framework] then would we automatically have ownership of all its synonyms, or would they have to also be sponsored separately?

Comment: Hi Kyle. I'm just a community moderator, not an employee of the company, so I really can't comment on the operation of sponsored tags. I certainly can't make you any guarantees. What I would say is that we *strongly* prefer not to have ambiguous tags, simply for practical reasons of categorization, so if [botframework] (or [bot-framework]?) starts becoming a generic tag because other companies/projects start using the name beyond just Microsoft, we would want to disambiguate the tag at that time, adding the "ms-" prefix or whatever is necessary.

Comment: In other words, your interest in maintaining a tag specific to Microsoft is also in the interest of the larger community, albeit for a different reason. I do not think that sponsorship has anything to do with synonyms, but I don't think that is really relevant here. If you want an official opinion from someone in the company, I recommend either using the [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form, or emailing the ad sales department.

Comment: @CodyGray - I've heard back from the company and I'm thinking the best thing to do is just reverse my request by making [microsoft-bot-framework] a synonym of [botframework], thus ensuring that [botframework] remains sponsored. Is that doable?